# Is the pathspace of a CW complex locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a CW complex and $I$ denote the closed interval $[0,1]$.
Equip the path space $X^I = \operatorname{Map}(I,X)$, the set of continuous map from $I$ to $X$, with the compact-open topology.
Is it true that $X^I$ is locally compact?
If not, what are the common conditions to make it so?
(I ultimately care about the case when $X$ is a manifold.)
How about $X^{\mathbb{R}^1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $X^I$ is never locally compact unless $X$ is $0$-dimensional (and similarly for $X^{\mathbb{R}}$).  If $X$ has positive dimension, then in particular it contains a closed subspace homeomorphic to $I$ and so $X^I$ contains a closed subspace homeomorphic to $I^I$, so it suffices to show that $I^I$ is not locally compact.  In this case the compact-open topology is just the topology of uniform convergence.  Now take any sequence $(f_n)$ in $I^I$ with no accumulation point (say, $f_n(x)=x^n$).  We can scale down this sequence to assume the $f_n$'s are all arbitrarily small in the sup norm, and then translate them to be contained in any open ball in the sup norm.  So, $I^I$ is nowhere locally compact: every nonempty open set contains a sequence with no accumulation point.

Comment: Note that the basic argument applies to the compact-open mapping space $Y^X$ whenever $Y$ is a Hausdorff space containing a non-trivial path.